# Why does defaultProps with interface not allowed ? mark in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-props

After typeScript 3.0 support defaultPoops function, but it combine with interface make wired behavior, when we set defaultPoops, interface params is not allowed to add ? mark, or it will make defaultPoops fail, but by literary thinking, setting defaultPoops should set ? mark in interface, because it means I have defaultPoops so I allow customers setting params or not, but the implement now doesn't do like that. Anyone can explain why and all behavior implement thinking in defaultPoops of typescript?

Code Example :

```
import React from "react"

interface Props {
  name: string; // default props work
}

const Test = ({name}: Props) => {
  return <div>Hello ${name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
}


const defaultProps = { name: 'aa'};
Test.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Test

<Test/> // compiler OK
```

```
import React from "react"

interface Props {
  name?: string; // default props don't work
}

const Test = ({name}: Props) => {
  return <div>Hello ${name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
}


const defaultProps = { name: 'aa'};
Test.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Test
<Test/> // compiler not OK, it tell you name possible is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does defaultProps with interface not allowed ? mark in typescript

Default props are not optional *for the component*. They are always provided (by React) and therefore not optional when you access `props`.

## More

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30251

[image]